# iPhone: Selecting a contact and loading into custom application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to build a application that allows the user to either A) enter a new person, or B) select a person from their contacts... My question is on item B. I've read briefly about loading Modal view controllers, but, was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a tutorial or article talking specifically about that kind of use case scenario.

Yes, I am also somewhat new to iPhone application development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your view controller should implement ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate protocol
2. You show the peoplepicker something like:

> ```
>     ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController =
>     [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
>     peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
>
>     [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:YES];
>
>     [peoplePickerController release];
> ```

```
3. And you might want to implement the optional methods as:

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString *name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
    // do something with name.. and release

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for this answer - I found someone that had implemented this exact set of methods.

Just what I needed.

Comment: Thanks Prakash.  Be sure to add the AddressBook and AddressBookUI Frameworks and put #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h> and #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h> in your .h file.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update everyone (and please correct me if I am going about this improperly), I've found this resource: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/index.html